# Null element Javascript with display:none

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have created a page where `element1.style.display='none'` by default. Now I have another element, `element2`, which when clicked displays `element1`. But when trying to set the `element1` to a function which sets `element1.style.display="block"` , it gives me an error saying `element1` is null. I understand this is because `display=none` by default.

How can I solve this issue? This is using Javascript and not jQuery.

```
var hash = location.hash; 
alert(hash); 

function init() { 
    if( hash == '#menu-a' || hash == '' ) { 
        document.getElementById('menu-a').style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else if( hash == '#menu-b' ) { 
        document.getElementById('menu-b').style.display = 'block'; 
    }
    else { 
        document.getElementById('menu-c').style.display = 'block'; 
    } 
} 

window.onload=init;
```

Comment: Got the error, it was a typo in using the name of the id.such a silly mistake and I spent a lot of time fixing it. Lesson learned from this

Answer (score 1):

> I understand this is because display=none by default

No. It is because nothing has been assigned to the variable.

I'm guessing you are expecting an element with `id="element1"` to automatically create a JavaScript variable called `element1` — it shouldn't.

```
document.getElementById('element1').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the hidden element is always in the same order you could try accessing it with getElementsByTagName("")[arrayindex].

Comment: Having a reference to an element should fine and enough. Most likely it is a scope problem and `element1` is not visible from where he wants to access it. But without code there is really nothing one can say about this (a better solution would be to give the element an ID and use `getElementById`).

Comment: tl;dr version: getElementById in a correct envoirenment is the best solution. You are right.

Full comment: I assumed - as no code is provided - that all elements are ided properly and getElementById was still not working. While getElementById of course is the best solution I just wanted to provide some quick solution to try and solve this problem cosmeticly so it can be worked on with less pressure.

Comment: Here's the code var hash = location.hash;
alert(hash) ;
function init()
{
    
    if( hash == '#menu-a' || hash == '' ) {
          document.getElementById('menu-a').style.display = 'block';
    } else if( hash == '#menu-b' ) {
          document.getElementById('menu-b').style.display = 'block';
    }else{
          document.getElementById('menu-c').style.display = 'block';
        }
}
window.onload=init;

Comment: What we need to diagnose - or rather confirm - our hunch we would also need the html code. Or you can check yourself if the element1 has id="element1" set in it's tag.

Comment: The html code is <div id="menu-a" style="display:block"> </div> <div id="menu-b"  style="display:none"> </div><div id="menu-c"  style="display:none"> </div>

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I did not vote you down.All your help is very valuable to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is any chance to have javascript triggered before dom ready? `element1` exists in dom tree at the moment you want to access it?

Answer (score 0):

You should do `display:block` shortly when `element` is initialized, and then revert it to `display:none` right after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I was actaully having a similar problem: not all browsers treat Elements with `display:none` (or at least their children) the same way. I have some SVG Objects placed in two DIVs and I want to show either one or the other. During initialization I do some manipulations on the SVG Elements (change some text Elements inside the SVG). This worked perfectly with Firefox but failed with Opera, Chrome and IE.
In these browsers Elements that were inside a div with `display:none` gave a null result when trying to get them with `document.getElementById(myID)`. A first workaround was to set the `display:none` property only after initialization (this worked), but when I wanted to show them again all initialization was lost (text labels were all at their default).
I think this proves that the content of a DIV with `display:none` is somehow cleared from the DOM, not simply hidden.
I tried also to use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none` but this made a big mess with the page layout. The only solution that seems to work on all browsers is (so far) to place the DIV I want to hide in "outer-space" like  [it is suggested here...](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/)

```
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are changing the style of that element before even that element is generated in your html page. When you try to access some element in a webpage, if that element is not available in the page at that point of time, it returns `Null`
My suggestion is to run that javascript part after those elements are loaded completely, by using attributes like, `onclick`, `onload`, etc...